# Clients can make maximum 15 connections to linux custom server in mono

Tags: mono, client, tcplistener

I have a custom server in C# being run on Ubuntu 11.10 under mono. I can make up to 15 silverlight clients connect to the server. When I make the 16th, it just waits. And if I close one of the established connections, the 16th client is able to connect. I am also not exceeding any file handle limit. The limit is 1024 and I am having around 300.

I have also run the same server on an Ubuntu 11.10 virtual machine and was able to make up to 20 connections.

The clients use TcpListener.

I don't get this limitation when running the server on windows.

Any ideas how to allow more connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using mono 2.6.7. Upgrading to 2.10.8 solves the problem.